# Finding Modified Tables in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

So I am trying to fix a dataload but I need to know which tables are being changed when I do a specific action in my webapp. Is there a way to examine the database queries even though they are coming from my app or at least a way to find out which tables are being modified so I could track the changes manually? This is with Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - to do a backup of you db and compare it after web app action else just add kind of audit triggers. Surely you could mess about flashback queries. You could enable trace with required level of detalization as well in order to see your sql.

For instance

```
SELECT * FROM employees
 AS OF TIMESTAMP
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2004-04-04 09:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11g you can use ASH (Active Session History) to find which SQL was active at a given time. You do need a license for tuning or diagnostics pack to legally use this. See [Oracle Active Session History (ASH)](http://psoug.org/reference/ash.html) for a little demo.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this:

```
EXEC dbms_output.enable(1000000);
DECLARE
  lc_seq_value VARCHAR(50);
  CURSOR table_list(p_field_like VARCHAR2) IS
    SELECT table_name  
      FROM all_tables
      WHERE table_name LIKE UPPER(p_field_like);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN table_list('TEST%') LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT TO_CHAR(SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(MAX(ORA_ROWSCN))) FROM '||
      i.table_name INTO lc_seq_value;
    dbms_output.put_line(lc_seq_value);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```